# Команда shell_exec php выполняется 2 раза, почему?

Tags: php, mongodb, php7

Странное поведение команды shell_exec: при выполнении она выполняется 2 раза... почему??? результат выполнения: 2 созданных архива с временем, различающимся на 2 секунды.

```
        $cmd = 'mongodump --db ' . $dbname .
            ' --gzip --archive=' . Yii::getAlias('@app') . '/backups/db/' . $dbname . '_' . date("d.m.Y_h:i:s") . '.gz' .
            ' --username ' . Yii::$app->mongodb->options['username'] .
            ' --password ' . Yii::$app->mongodb->options['password'];
    shell_exec($cmd);
```

Comment: Запросто может быть багом `php`, какую версию используете? Пробовали запускать на других версиях `php`? И каким образом вызывается этот код? Из командной строки или через веб-интерфейс? Возможно к скрипту обращаются дважды?

Comment: php 7.2.24, на других версиях не проверял, не на чем.. скрипт вызывается один раз (это точно, првоерено). скрипт вызывается через веб интерфейс вызовом действия контроллера. Та же строка в командной оболочке напрямую создает только один архив.

Comment: на php7.3 то же самое

Comment: Тогда вызывается из веб дважды - разбирайтесь почему.